# SherlockFragemtActivity tab is unable to pouplate the data into Listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm learning development about Sherlock ActionBar, I have created a sample program using Sherlock ActionBar to populate date from the database to the listview.

For I have created two tabs in one activity, the first tab(fragment1) which i used to enter the details works fine, but the second tab(fragment2) which need the data to be populated into the listview isn't working fine.

Please take a look at my code:

Fragment2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends SherlockFragment implements TabListener {
     private Fragment mFragment;

     DBAdapter db;
     Cursor c;
     ListView list;
     MyAdapter myAdapter;
     View view ;

     Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.details_listview);

        db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
        db.openDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_listview, null);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

         list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          registerForContextMenu(list);
         updateListView();
    }

    private void updateListView() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        c = db.getAllRecords();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mFragment = new Fragment2();        
          ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
            ft.attach(mFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.remove(mFragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        Context context;

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return c.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public android.view.View getView(int position, android.view.View conview,
                ViewGroup arg2) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            conview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customllistview, null);

            TextView t1 = (TextView)conview.findViewById(R.id.idtextView);
            TextView t2 = (TextView)conview.findViewById(R.id.nametextView);
            TextView t3 = (TextView)conview.findViewById(R.id.locationtextView);

            c.moveToPosition(position);

            String id = c.getString(0);
            String name = c.getString(1);
            String location = c.getString(2);

            t1.setText("row id: "+id);
            t2.setText("name :"+name);
            t3.setText("location :"+location);


            return conview;
        }

    }

}
```

Databse adapter for databse:
DBAdapter.java

```
public class DBAdapter {

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    String DATABASE_NAME = "sampleDB";
    String TABLE_NAME = "sample";

    String COL_ROWID = "rowid";
    String COL_NAME ="name";
    String COL_LOCATION = "location";

    String CREATE_TABLE = "create table sample(rowid integer primary key autoincrement,name text not null,location text not null) ";

    public DBAdapter(Context c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = c;
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    DBAdapter openDatabase() {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    long insertRecord(String name, String location) {
        ContentValues con = new ContentValues();
        con.put(COL_NAME, name);
        con.put(COL_LOCATION, location);

        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, con);

    }

    Cursor getAllRecords(){
        String[] columns = {COL_ROWID,COL_NAME,COL_LOCATION};
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    }

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }


}
```

And finally here is my logcat output:

```
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.example.sherlocklistview.Fragment2$MyAdapter.getView(Fragment2.java:111)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:701)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:311)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-22 18:54:16.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1204):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Kindly provide some solution for my problem

Comment: Not sure if there are any other problems in your code, but `context` variable inside `MyAdapter` is null.

Comment: @Vikram, you are correct I have added arguments to the MyAdapter to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide information about which line is exactly the 111 line in your file Fragment2.java (taking into account the import line numbers).
Check your context variable in MyAdapter in Fragment2.java, as it looks like it is not initialized anywhere.

Comment: Blow is the code at line 111:                                                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);